# Why does this code produce a nil following a Proc.call?

Tags: ruby, irb, proc-object

```
C:\>irb
irb(main):001:0> s = Proc.new { puts "Hello" }
=> #<Proc:0x04051780@(irb):1>
irb(main):002:0> s.call
Hello
=> nil
```

What causes the nil?

```
ruby 1.8.6 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 287) [i386-mswin32]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>`s` does not return a value,</s> As @sepp2k points out in the comment, `puts` returns `nil`, so `nil` automatically becomes the return value since that is the last statement in the proc.

It just gets printed to the terminal as the return value of the last statement, similar to that cryptic output after you assign the proc to `s`.

Comment: More accurately: s returns the value that is returned by puts and puts returns nil.

Comment: I haven't used Ruby much, I was just going by paradigms from other languages. Thanks and answer updated.

Comment: There seems to be an (understandable) assumption that if x happens in y, and y is something you've tried for the first time, x must be because of y. Is there any term for this apart from "post hoc ergo proper hoc"?